# How to use range in Excel formula criteria

Tags: excel

I have requirement where I have range for which I want to perform count. Because there is a condition, I want to use COUNTIF/COUNTIFS function. In criteria, I want to use range as I have multiple value that can be matched. Following is an example

Values to be counted - APPLE, MANGO, ORANGE, MANGO, APPLE, APPLE, ORANGE, ORANGE

What I want is count for APPLE and ORANGE for example but I want to keep it generelized. That means in another column I want to put values for which I want count. So at a time I can put only APPLE, at another time APPLE, MANGO and so on. If I'm still not clear enough then in another words, I want a count of values which are determined by the values in another range.

I could not find any way to use range in the 'criteria' parameter of the COUNTIF/COUNTIFS function. I know I can use sum of multiple COUNTIF with different value in each 'criteria' but that becomes hardcoded and everytime I need to change the formula.

Can someone help with how can I use a range (instead of single value) in 'criteria' ?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(data_range,criteria_range))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your data list is in column A and your "values to be counted" occupy, say, D1:D5.

In cell B1, use `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$D$1:$D$5,1,FALSE)),0,1)`. This will write 1 if A1 appears in D1:D5, 0 otherwise.

Copy this formula downwards. Note that it will return 0 for a blank cell so you can extend this formula as far as you like thereby future-proofing your sheet.

In another cell, sum column B, `=SUM(B1:B...)` Where `B...` is the end of the formula range.

I don't think you can arrive at the final formula in one step using arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you investigate the Excel formula DCOUNT

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/dcount-HP005209049.aspx

Microsoft even use a fruit based example for you !

Answer (score 0):

`CountIf` accepts a *range*, and a *criteria*.  The *criteria* can reference a range.

For example:

`=CountIf(A:A,"Apple")` counts the number of occurrences of the word "Apple" in column A.

And:

`=CountIf(A:A,B2)` counts the number of occurrences of *whatever value is in Cell `B2`, in column A.

If you use **two** cells to define the search criteria, say, `B2` and `C2`, you could do:

`=CountIf(A:A,B2)+CountIf(A:A,C2)`

Or using `CountIfs`:

`=CountIfs(A:A,B2,A:A,C2)`

If you *must* put both search criteria in a single cell (seems like a problem of bad worksheet structure, rather than any good design requirement), then you can modify the *criteria* of any of the above functions using string functions:

Ex: Say your criteria of `Apple, Orange` is a single cell, `C2`, delimited by the comma:

`=CountIf(A:A,Trim(MID(C2,1,FIND(",",C2)-1))) + CountIf(A:A,TRIM(MID(C2,FIND(",",C2)+1,LEN(C2)))`

I still think you're better served using a proper `CountIfs` or summing two `CountIf` with indpendent criteria ranges, rather trying to troubleshoot errors, or build complex formula (i.e., modify the above to work even if there is no comma, or a single value, etc....)